# Error binding to target method in C#3.0

Tags: reflection, c#-3.0, delegates

I am trying to hook Up a Delegate Using Reflection. This is what I have done so far

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;

namespace ChartHelper
{
    public class ICChartHelper
    {        

        public void RefreshChart()
        {
            try
            {   
                Assembly myobj = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\sample.dll");

                foreach (Type mytype in myobj.GetTypes())
                {

                    if (mytype.IsClass == true)
                    {
                        if (mytype.FullName.EndsWith("." + "ICAutomationProxy"))
                        {
                            // create an instance of the object
                            object ClassObj = Activator.CreateInstance(mytype);

               //  var eventTypes = mytype.GetEvents();

                            EventInfo evClick = mytype.GetEvent("OnRefreshCompleted");
                            Type tDelegate = evClick.EventHandlerType;

                            MethodInfo miHandler =
                           typeof(ChartHelper.ICChartHelper)
                           .GetMethod("RefreshApplication",
                            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

                            Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(tDelegate,typeof(ChartHelper.ICChartHelper), miHandler);

                            MethodInfo addHandler = evClick.GetAddMethod();
                            Object[] addHandlerArgs = { d };
                            addHandler.Invoke(ClassObj, addHandlerArgs);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private void RefreshApplication(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Bingo");
        }
```

But in the

**Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(tDelegate,typeof(ChartHelper.ICChartHelper), miHandler);**

line, I am encountering the error `Error binding to target method`

I have also found the discusion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714989/delegate-createdelegate-and-generics-error-binding-to-target-method) and tried to solve the same but with no luck.

I need help to understand what wrong I am doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is an instance method, so you need to use an overload of `CreateDelegate` which takes the target of the delegate, and pass in an instance of the declaring type. For example:

```
Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(tDelegate, new ICChartHelper(), miHandler);
```

Note that you don't need to call `GetAddMethod` on the `EventInfo` and invoke that using reflection - you can just use [`EventInfo.AddEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.addeventhandler.aspx).