# Create delegate type in runtime

Tags: c#, .net

I try create delegate type using an Expression class, but when I try create delegate from instance of MethodInfo I've got an ArgumentException. I using .NET 4.0
Here code:

```
        var method = /*...*/;
        List<Type> tArgs = new List<Type> { method.ReturnType };
        var mparams = method.GetParameters();
        mparams.ToList().ForEach(p => tArgs.Add(p.ParameterType));
        var delDecltype = Expression.GetDelegateType(tArgs.ToArray());
        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(delDecltype, method);
```

P.S.  Sorry for my bad english;)

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714989/delegate-createdelegate-and-generics-error-binding-to-target-method/2715050#2715050) the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you read [the documentation for `Expression.GetDelegateType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.getdelegatetype.aspx), you would see that the return type has to be the *last* argument.

That means this code should work:

```
var tArgs = new List<Type>();
foreach (var param in method.GetParameters())
    tArgs.Add(param.ParameterType);
tArgs.Add(method.ReturnType);
var delDecltype = Expression.GetDelegateType(tArgs.ToArray());
return Delegate.CreateDelegate(delDecltype, method);
```

This code works for static methods only though. If you want create a delegate from instance method, you need to provide the instance you want to call the method on. To do that, change the last line to:

```
return Delegate.CreateDelegate(delDecltype, instance, method);
```

Comment: It's didn't help. Same exception: ArgumentException "Error when linking with the final method."

Comment: See edit, you probably have instance method, which means you need to provide the instance.

Comment: Is there any way how to create dynamically also an delegate with `params` keyword for the last parameter type?

Comment: @Mvorisek Not with `Expression.GetDelegateType`. I think you would need to use Reflection Emit to do that.

Comment: @svick Isn't `params` just a syntax sugar though? I believe for `params object[]` you should only specify `object[]`.