# How to get .net managed method pointer by "MethodName" that can be called on native code

Tags: c#, reflection, interop, clr, cil

### Precondition

The .net method that I will get its pointer is:

- public static method
- have no overloads
- arguments and return value just ValueType (unsafe pointer, primitive type, unmanaged struct)

### Reason

Get the method pointer so I can call in C++ program.

This works for me but I need to declare delegate for every method.

I want to get rid of doing things over and over again.

In .net side:

```cs
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate void UpdateDelegate(float delta);

public static void* GetUpdatePointer()
{
    var delegateInstance = = new UpdateDelegate(Update);
    var pfnUpdate = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(delegateInstance);
    return (void*)pfnUpdate;
}
public static Update(float delta)=>{...}
```

In C++ side:

```cpp
typedef void (_stdcall *  FuncPtr)(float);
void foo()
{
    //just pseudo-code showing where is the pfnUpdate from.
    FuncPtr pfnUpdate = (FuncPtr)GetUpdatePointer();
    pfnUpdate(0.01f);
}
```

### what I want

In c#, I export GetMethodPointer for my native code. It will return a function pointer to specified method, and this pointer can be invoked by native program via stdcall calling convention.

```cs
//avoid gc collect this object
static List<Delegate> KeepReference = new List<Delegate>();
public unsafe static void* GetMethodPointer(string name)
{
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(PhysicsMain).GetMethod(name);

    // also mark this delegate with [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)] attribute
    Type delegateType = ConstructDelegateTypeWithMethodInfo(methodInfo);

    var delegateInstance = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, methodInfo);

    KeepReference.Add(delegateInstance);
    return (void*)Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(delegateInstance);
}
```

I need ConstructDelegateTypeWithMethodInfo to create a delegate with the same signature as the specified method. And mark [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)] attribute for it so that can be marshaled as a function pointer.

I think it may using IL, Reflection, even Asm to do this. Or using IL to write the whole GetMethodPointer method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got a solution these days. Firstly, I came across `Expression.GetDelegateType` given by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047440/create-delegate-type-in-runtime). But it did't work for me, because `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` doesn't support generic delegate type generate by `Expression.GetDelegateType`.  I thought there might be a clue in implementation of `Expression.GetDelegateType`. So,  I browsed [referencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/DelegateHelpers.Generated.cs,d829ef0933f98ee5) and got a internal method called `MakeNewCustomDelegate`. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699394/c-sharp-getdelegateforfunctionpointer-with-generic-delegate) gives code about how to call the internal method.  Things are readily solved!

Edit: I forgot to say, the default unmanaged calling convension of a delegate is stdcall, so we don't need to mark the delegate with [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)] explicitly.

Comment: I provided another example how this can be implemented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188743/15495138)

Answer (score 0):

In your example you assume that the class of the method is know function (`PhysicsMain`).

If `UpdateDelegate` is also known you can use it easily:

```
Type delegateType = typeof(UpdateDelegate);
var delegateInstance = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, methodInfo);
```

But you can also get this type by name only:

```
Type delegateType = Type.GetType("Namespace.ClassName+UpdateDelegate");
var delegateInstance = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, methodInfo);
```

You can look at `delegateType.CustomAttributes` and verify that the type has `UnmanagedFunctionPointer` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn’t express it clearly. There 's no delegate type called "UpdateDelegate". There's no delegate predefined. Because there were many methods with different signature, I don't want to predefine delegate for each method. I just want to generate the delegate type at runtime using MethodInfo. And actually, the MethodInfo do contains all infomation about constructing a delegate type for this method. But thanks for your help.