# Error: ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type. in dot net core6

Tags: html, asp.net-core, delegates, html-helper, tag-helpers

> Error: ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type

This is in .NET Core 6; I wanted to add custom html helper textbox which was working in ASP.NET MVC, but it's not working when used in ASP.NET Core.

`EditorExtension` method is posted here where delegate error is occurring. and also content some existing helper templates as well. I'm trying to convert this ASP.NET MVC code to ASP.NET Core MVC.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;

using RateChangingSystemCore1.MetadataProviders;
using RateChangingSystemCore1.Models;
using RateChangingSystemCore1;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace RateChangingSystemCore1.Extensions
{
    public static class EditorExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Access to the log4Net logging object
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        private static MethodInfo _inputHelper;
        private static Func<IHtmlHelper, InputType, ModelMetadata, string, object, bool, bool, bool, bool, string, IDictionary<string, object>, HtmlString> _inputHelper2;
        private static MethodInfo _checkBoxHelper;
        private static MethodInfo _textAreaHelper;
    
        static EditorExtensions()
        {
            _inputHelper = typeof(System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions).GetMethod("InputHelper", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    
            // private static MvcHtmlString InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, string name, object value, bool useViewData, bool isChecked, bool setId, bool isExplicitValue, string format, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
            // Creates a delegate so that reflection doesn't have to be used to call each time and this method it much faster. 
            // Verbose due to the number of parameters being passed though but it's just InputExtensions.InputHelper from MVC
            // http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs
    
            Delegate @delegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IHtmlHelper, InputType, ModelMetadata, string, object, bool, bool, bool, bool, string, IDictionary<string, object>, HtmlString>), _inputHelper);
            _inputHelper2 = (Func<IHtmlHelper, InputType, ModelMetadata, string, object, bool, bool, bool, bool, string, IDictionary<string, object>, HtmlString>)@delegate;
           
            _checkBoxHelper = typeof(System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions).GetMethod("CheckBoxHelper", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            _textAreaHelper = typeof(System.Web.Mvc.Html.TextAreaExtensions).GetMethod("TextAreaHelper", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    
        }
    
        private static CoopMetadataProvider metadataProvider = new CoopMetadataProvider();
    
        private static ModelMetadata GetDefinitionMetaData(Definition definition)
        {
            if (HttpContextHelper.Current.Items["definitionMetaDataCache"] is Dictionary<int, ModelMetadata> definitionMetaDataCache)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                definitionMetaDataCache = new Dictionary<int, ModelMetadata>();
    
                HttpContextHelper.Current.Items["definitionMetaDataCache"] = definitionMetaDataCache;
            }
    
            if (definitionMetaDataCache.ContainsKey(definition.NodeID))
            {
                return (ModelMetadata)definitionMetaDataCache[definition.NodeID];
            }
    
            log.DebugFormat("Making meta data for {0}", definition.NodeID);
    
            // Get the model meta data using our custom provider (have to do this this way as CreatMetaData is a protected method
            var modelMetadata = metadataProvider.CreateMetadata2(null, typeof(Definition), () => definition, typeof(Definition), null);
    
            definitionMetaDataCache[definition.NodeID] = modelMetadata;
    
            return modelMetadata;
        }

        private static HtmlString CoopEditorCommon(this IHtmlHelper html, string name, object value, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, Definition definition, Func<ModelMetadata, object, HtmlString> inputHelper)
        {
            // ViewData, ModelMetadata, Model, TemplateInfo contain all the information relating to the property and what should be rendered
            //var viewData = new IDictionary(htmlAttributes.Keys, htmlAttributes.Values);

\#pragma warning disable CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
definition = definition ?? html.ViewData\["Definition"\] as Definition;
\#pragma warning restore CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

            // Get the model meta data using our custom provider (have to do this this way as CreateMetaData is a protected method
            var modelMetadata = GetDefinitionMetaData(definition);
    
            object formattedModelValue = definition.ValueValue; // modelMetadata.Model;

\#pragma warning disable CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
string formatString = modelMetadata.EditFormatString;
\#pragma warning restore CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

            if (modelMetadata.ModelType != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatString))
            {
                formattedModelValue = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, formatString, definition.ValueValue); // modelMetadata.Model
            }
    
            return inputHelper(modelMetadata, formattedModelValue);
        }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Custom version of Html.Editor for specific use in this project to generate the Model Meta Data from
        /// the properties 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="html"></param>
        /// <param name="definition"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static HtmlString CoopTextBox(this IHtmlHelper html, string name, object value, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            return CoopEditorCommon(html, name, value, htmlAttributes, null, (modelMetadata, formattedModelValue) =>
            {
                var result = _inputHelper2(html, InputType.Text, modelMetadata, "", formattedModelValue, false, false, true, true, null, htmlAttributes);
    
                return result;
                /*
                return (MvcHtmlString)_inputHelper.Invoke(obj: null, parameters: new object[] {
                    html, InputType.Text, modelMetadata, "", formattedModelValue, false, false, true, true, null, htmlAttributes
                });
                */
            });
        }
    
        public static HtmlString CoopTextBox(this IHtmlHelper html, string name, object value, Definition definition, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            return CoopEditorCommon(html, name, value, htmlAttributes, definition, (modelMetadata, formattedModelValue) =>
            {
                var result = _inputHelper2(html, InputType.Text, modelMetadata, name, formattedModelValue, false, false, true, true, null, htmlAttributes);
    
                return result;
            });
        }
    
        public static HtmlString CoopCheckBoxFor(this IHtmlHelper html, string name, object value, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            return CoopEditorCommon(html, name, value, htmlAttributes, null, (modelMetadata, formattedModelValue) =>
            {
                return (HtmlString)_checkBoxHelper.Invoke(obj: null, parameters: new object[] {
                    html, modelMetadata, "", formattedModelValue, htmlAttributes
                });
            });
        }
    
        public static HtmlString CoopCheckBoxFor(this IHtmlHelper html, string name, object value, Definition definition, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            return CoopEditorCommon(html, name, value, htmlAttributes, definition, (modelMetadata, formattedModelValue) =>
            {
                return (HtmlString)_checkBoxHelper.Invoke(obj: null, parameters: new object[] {
                    html, modelMetadata, name, formattedModelValue, htmlAttributes
                });
            });
        }
    
        public static HtmlString CoopMultiLineBox(this IHtmlHelper html, string name, object value, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            var definition = html.ViewData["Definition"] as Definition;
    
            return html.CoopEditorCommon(name, value, htmlAttributes, null, (modelMetadata, formattedModelValue) =>
            {
                modelMetadata = (ModelMetadata)formattedModelValue;

\#pragma warning disable CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
return (HtmlString)\_textAreaHelper.Invoke(obj: null, parameters: new object\[\] {
html, modelMetadata, "", null, htmlAttributes, null
});
\#pragma warning restore CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
//return (MvcHtmlString)method.Invoke(obj: null, parameters: new object\[\] {
//    html, InputType.Text, modelMetadata, "", formattedModelValue, false, false, true, true, null, htmlAttributes
//});
});
}

        public static HtmlString CoopMultiLineBox(this IHtmlHelper html, string name, object value, Definition definition, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            return html.CoopEditorCommon(name, value, htmlAttributes, definition, (modelMetadata, formattedModelValue) =>
            {
                // modelMetadata.Model = formattedModelValue;
                modelMetadata = (ModelMetadata)formattedModelValue;
                return (HtmlString)_textAreaHelper.Invoke(obj: null, parameters: new object[] {
                        html, modelMetadata, name, null, htmlAttributes, null
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piJ0X.png)

Comment: As described in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74341858/18789859), should you also provide an instance parameter?